# internal app can not import com.android.internal.policy.impl?

Tags: android, build

I added an app in packages/apps in android build system and my app use some internal api.But when I use mm or mmm to make the app,android build system shows error:package com.android.internal.policy.impl does not exist etc.But I saw Phone app also uses internal api like com.android.internal.xx and it builds with no errors.I want to know whether there are something i missed and how can i use internal api in internal apps.BTW,my app can import com.android.internal.telephony,but cannot import com.android.internal.policy.impl.Thanks.

Comment: you have to change the access policy of the jar (in the build section, in eclipse)

Comment: It's not eclipse thing,I work in build system environment,working on system app,and one of my app needs to import com.android.internal.policy.impl.xxxs.java,but build system show errors like com.android.internal.policy.impl does not exist.

Comment: A/ check in the jar if the class is indeed present. if it is, B/ check the content of the manifest. there may be the access rules there that forbids biding to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I add `LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android.policy framework` in Android.mk, and it works.

Comment: In my case adding just `android.policy` was enough.